# Issue removing wrapper: simple WebView Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, webview

OK - so now that I've gotten this Android "WebView" application to work, is there a way around this wrapper? The wrapper shows around the webpage with the "____ Browse" module still allowing you to browse elsewhere. Aside from this, the entire thing works beautifully.

Is there something in the XML etc that I can change to remove this wrapped, and display the full web page rather than with any extra?

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/images/android_webview2.jpg An example of the wrapper (which is the space around the page, text input, and "Browse" button)

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. Please upload a screenshot somewhere and link to it, to illustrate what this "wrapper" is.

Comment: @CommonsWare sure thing. It is pretty standard across any web view. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/images/android_webview2.jpg

Comment: @CommonsWare Would prefer if possible the content shows. That's it. No Browse button, nothing padding it (unless it's in the HTML). Again; I am not even sure if it is possible - that is why I asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It is pretty standard across any web view

No, it is not.

> Is there something in the XML etc that I can change to remove this wrapped, and display the full web page rather than with any extra?

Yes. You can get rid of the `EditText` widget, the `Button` widget, and perhaps other stuff as well.

Let's assume for the moment that the layout XML in question is [the one that you put in your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23598003/issue-creating-simple-webview-android):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   tools:context=".MainActivity" >

   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="@string/hello_world" />

   <EditText
      android:id="@+id/urlField"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView1"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:ems="10" />

   <Button
      android:id="@+id/button1" 
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="@+id/urlField"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:onClick="open"
      android:text="@string/browse" />

   <WebView
      android:id="@+id/webView1"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_below="@+id/button1" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

If you do not want the `Button`, delete the `Button`.

If you do not want the `EditText`, delete the `EditText`.

If you do not want the `TextView`, delete the `TextView`.

If, after all of the above, you have only the `RelativeLayout` and the `WebView`,  you could even get rid of the `RelatitveLayout`.

Comment: OK - I solely meant to note that I have seen it in every example. I should have been more specific. That being said; ok. This makes perfect sense, and sure - I am a dumbass. I noted previously that I have no experience with this, and am coming here for help. Go easy, chief. I will try the above solution and get back to you/choose your answer. Thank you

Comment: Thanks for the help. As this has removed all the extra BS (button, text input), which I suspected needed to be done anyway - I have accepted your answer.

Comment: I will say though, removing the RelativeLayout tag causes the app to crash (and yes, did so cleanly). The borders around the content on every side you see in the example still show in my "app" as well. If you have any idea how to remove them (or if maybe they're the relative layout or some setting within it), that would be a helpful additional piece of info.

Comment: @TonyLaManna: "removing the RelativeLayout tag causes the app to crash" -- use LogCat and examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash. "The borders around the content on every side you see in the example" -- I don't see borders (usually defined as being of some non-background color). I see padding or margins, and looking at your XML, that is from the four `android:padding*` attributes in the `RelativeLayout`.